# PHP mysql select returning null values inside response object

Tags: php, mysql

I can't find anything similar when searching.
I'm doing the following in XAMPP for Windows 10:

When the query below is run in PHP, the result object contains null values in its fields. The result itself is not null, it's all the fields inside:

```
$getSessionsQuery = "select * from transaction";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $getSessionsQuery);
// returns: 
//{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
// same results if I run $result = $conn->query($getSessionsQuery);
```

However, when executing the same query in phpMyAdmin, I get all the rows I had inserted.  This is odd, because the table rows were populated by PHP code.

[Screenshot of query results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6ggo.png)

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong in the PHP?

Comment: since when `mysqli_query()` returns JSON and not boolean?

Comment: Where is $conn defined and in what context do you run your query (inside a function etc.)?

Comment: $conn = new mysqli("server_ip", "dbUser", "dbUserPassword", "dbName");
    $getSessionsQuery = "select * from `transaction`;";

    echo "\n\n// GET SESSION :    ".$getSessionsQuery."\n";

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else{
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $getSessionsQuery);        
        echo "// RESULT :    ".json_encode($result)."\n\n";
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **fetch** your query as **array**.

```
$query = $conn->query($getSessionsQuery);
```

Then, take all query results.

```
/** @var $res array = [int, array] */
$res = [];  

while ($r = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $res[] = $r;
}

$query->free(); // free result

return $res;
```

To make it looks simple, we can create it as function:

```
function getTransactions($conn, $query) : array {
 /** @var $res array = [int, array] */
 $res = [];

 $mQuery = $conn->query($query);
 while ($r = $mQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $res[] = $r;
 }

 $mQuery->free();

 return $res;
}
```

**Make sure** your query are valid! If you need more references, open [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: THAT'S IT - it worked! Thanks!

            $mQuery = $conn->query($getSessionsQuery);
            while ($r = $mQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                echo "\n// ".implode($r); 
             $res[] = $r;
            }

gives all my rows, stringified, one after the other,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously with you connection resource `$conn`. I have a guess, that this resource is not visible in the context, where you run your query. If you run it inside some class method or a function, then make this `$conn` resource visible to this method/function, for example by passing it as one of its arguments:

```
// in pseudo-code
public function method($conn, ...) {
    $getSessionsQuery = "select * from transaction";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $getSessionsQuery);
    ...
}
```

Comment: If $conn were not visible in this scope, wouldn't I get a null pointer exception? .... this is a more complete snippet: 
    $conn = new mysqli("server_ip", "dbUser", "dbUserPassword", "dbName");
    $getSessionsQuery = "select * from `transaction`;";
    echo "\n\n// GET SESSION :    ".$getSessionsQuery."\n";
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else{
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $getSessionsQuery);        
        echo "// RESULT :    ".json_encode($result)."\n\n";
    }

Answer (score 1):

Please encode your table name, `transaction` is a keyword in sql.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `transaction`";
```